# Is this statment legal in Java

Tags: java

```
num1 = randomNum.nextInt(20);
num2 = randomNum.nextInt(num1);
```

When I run this, i get
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.illigalArgumentException: bound must be possitive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Uknown Source)
at EquationMin.main(EquationMin.java:19)

Comment: num1 is zero in this case

Comment: @A.Wabbi So, how could I fix this issue?

Comment: `num2 = randomNum.nextInt(num1+1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory/from a syntax-POV: yes

But there's a problem:

> [Random#nextInt(int)] Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29). This means`num1` may actually turn out to be 0. But

> [Random#nextInt(int)] Throws:
>       IllegalArgumentException - if n is not positive

Since 0 per definition is not positive, this will cause a `IllegalArgumentException`.

The simplest workaround would be to simply add 1 to the parameter:

```
num1 = randomNum.nextInt(20);
num2 = randomNum.nextInt(num1 + 1);
```

to ensure, that the parameter for the second call of `nextInt` will never turn 0. Instead one could define a lower bound, like `Math.max(num1, 1)` or anything else.